# ¿Cómo graficar x + y = 0 con MatPlotLib en Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

He estado ultimamente graficando ecuaciones con python, ecuaciones de 3 incognitas y busque una guia por este medio y la conseguí, sin embargo, ahora estoy frente a una ecuación de dos incógnitas y es X + Y = 0;

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)

Xc, Yc = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# Zc = np.multiply((2*Yc), Xc)
# Zc2 = -(np.add((Xc**2), (Yc**2)))
Zc3 = np.add((Xc, Yc))

# Plot the surface.
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc3, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.coolwarm, rstride=5, cstride=5)

plt.show()
```

En las ecuaciones de 3 incógnitas, el procedimiento fue despejar una de ellas y calcular, sin embargo en esta ecuación solo tengo dos incógnitas y el plot_surface me pide 3 parametros, entonces intenté Z = X + Y pero obtuve un rombo, y teniendo como guía las graficas que permite realizar GeoGebra3D me sale que esa ecuación es para un plano diagonal o vertical.

No he podido hacerlo despejando una de las dos incógnitas porque plot_surface me pide 3 parametros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La lógica es similar pero en este caso en vez usar como variables independientes a las coordenadas "x" e "y", se debes usar "x" y "z" o "y" y "z".

Considerando lo anterior la solución es:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection="3d")

# Create data.
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
z = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
Y = -X

# Plot the surface.
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.coolwarm, rstride=5, cstride=5)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]